Can my control and treatment groups have the same t=-1 value for the dependent variable in an event study framework?
I am running an event study (Callaway and Santanna 2021 framework) in which my dependent variable is binary (1 if the person is declared as homeless, 0 otherwhise). I want to see the impact of the opening of a specific public facility on the probability of leaving homelessness. This facility opens at different years for different cities. The dataset consists only of people who are homeless at some point and live in cities where a facility opens at some point, so the control group is made of the not-yet-treated.
To implement this, I am planning to restrict the sample to only people who were homeless at t = -1 (the year before the facility opening), meaning that everyone would have the dependent variable equal to 1 in t = -1. Is this okay? Will it cause collinearity, or cause problems with the pretrends assumption?
Thanks in advance
